# Cannot set property 'onclick' of null navbar

Tags: javascript, php

Ok trying to acomplish modal using this script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var modal = document.querySelector('.slicknav_nav');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelector(".slicknav_btn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("butinco")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the HTML...

```
<div id="slick-mobile-menu">
<div class="slicknav_menu">
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" class="slicknav_btn slicknav_collapsed" style="outline: none;">
<span class="slicknav_menutxt">Menu</span><span class="slicknav_icon"><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span>
<ul class="slicknav_nav slicknav_hidden" style="touch-action: pan-y; display: none;" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
<li class="menu-item"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Result is:

```
Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

How to fix this?

Pretty hard to type or format a question, when everything is jumping around page while I am writting.

Comment: There's no element with class `butinco` in your HTML code ?!!

Comment: There is. its last after above html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your elements are not yet ready. Make sure you add your event listeners when the page is fully loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   // add your document.querySelector here, along with the rest of the code.
});
```

I'd recommend using for the click handlers as well.
`addEventListener('click' , function() { });` instead so you have more control.

Comment: your span variable is undefined. That's why. You do not have this span in the HTML. Try console.log(span) first to see if you're getting your HTML element.